# Is 'it' a pronoun or expletive in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, expletive-pronoun

> "Well, Ted," said the weatherman, "I don't know about that, but it's
>   not only the owls that have been acting oddly today. Viewers as far
>   apart as Kent, Yorkshire, and Dundee have been phoning in to tell me
>   that instead of the rain I promised yesterday, they've had a downpour
>   of shooting stars! Perhaps people have been celebrating Bonfire Night
>   early - **it**'s not until next week, folks! But I can promise a wet night
>   tonight." (Harry Potter)

Is ‘it’ a pronoun indicating Bonfire Night, or expletive (or dummy it)?

Comment: As you have guessed, it refers to Bonfire Night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it" refers to Bonfire Night. Put another way -

"people have been celebrating Bonfire Night early, because Bonfire Night's not until next week"